# Put values from SELECT to php array

Tags: mysql, php

I have an SQL SELECT request

```
select v.id
from wp_posts v
join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
where meta_key ='_price'
and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
and p.id = '1743'
```

It works well and returns me 2 values, each one in new line:

```
1744

1745
```

I'm trying to put this values to php array

```
$rbp_ids[] = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
select v.id from wp_posts v
join wp_postmeta pm on (pm.post_id = v.id)
join wp_posts p on (v.post_parent = p.id)
where meta_key ='_price'
and v.post_type = 'product_variation'
and p.id = '1743'"));
```

And do an echo function

```
foreach( $rbp_ids as $rbp_id){

echo $rbp_id

}
```

But this function returns me only one first value from select:

1744

Is it possible to make an array like (1744,1745)?

Answer (score 1):

Oh...i need to use  `$wpdb->get_col`

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? I assume that the `get_var` function only returns the first value in the first row fro the result set, while `get_col` loads all the results from one column into an array? But it's not clear from the context (for that matter, it's not clear that this is an answer to the question rather than a misplaced note that should have been edited into the question). If it is an answer and solves your problem, go ahead and accept it, so we know that for sure.